# How to configure redis object cache for multiple sites in the same server without errors

Tags: plugins, multisite, cache, nginx

I have about 50 sites in my server. I have installed redis to be used for cache and trying to cinfigure [redis object cache plugin.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redis-cache/) I have done all the configurations I have read. Without the WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT and WP_REDIS_DATABASE, all the domain links redirect to one website that has been cached.
Here is an example of my wp-config.php

```
define('WP_REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('WP_REDIS_PORT', '6379');
define('WP_REDIS_PREFIX', 'uniqueprefix_');
//define('WP_REDIS_DATABASE', 1);
define( 'WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT', 'domainname.tld:' );
```

From the code above, I have tried using a different database, but I get an error. Tried using WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT still getting an error. All solutions from this link [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/redis-cache-with-multiple-wordpress-sites/) have not worked.

Please help me figure out what I could be doing wrong.  I am using hestia cp (nginx + apache2)

Comment: How did you install Redis? Might be worth checking that it's running correctly, how you check will depend on the operating system of your host and how to installed Redis.

Comment: `sudo apt update
sudo apt install redis-server
sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf //here I bound my local ip address
sudo apt install php-redis 
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo service nginx restart `

Comment: You say you bound it to your local IP address, was that `127.0.0.1`? If not then you won't be able to connect through loopback, change your binding to `127.0.0.1` and then restart redis: `sudo service redis* restart`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue lately and you need to configure `WP_REDIS_PREFIX` in `wp-config.php`

```
define( 'WP_REDIS_PREFIX', 'your_unique_key_for_each_wp_instance_' );
```

for each WP site. This solved my case.

Comment: I have done that. You can see it in my question under the things I have tried to configure.
```define('WP_REDIS_PREFIX', 'uniqueprefix_');```